# how to report all tied positions for the last element in the list in JAVA

Tags: java

I have a task to print n frequently used words based on their count values across multiple files.
Now the issue is after printing n words, I have to print all the ties at the last position

for instance if I printed 10 frequently used words based on the highest count 
and the output comes like this when I use a for loop.

**CODE**

```
    int listSize = newList.size() >= 10 ? 10 : newList.size();

    for (int k = 0; k < listSize; k++) {

        Words w = newList.get(k);

        System.out.println("Word : " + ++j + " " + w.getWord() + " "
                + w.getCount());

        // System.out.println(w.getWord());

    }
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
word 1 : liked 104
word 2 : hello 98
....
....
....
word 10 : picnic 15
```

now If I encounter words further with the same count that is 15 I have to print them also
if I have five words with the same word count 15
I have to print all of them that is all ties for the last position must be reported like this

```
**OUTPUT :**


word 11 : camera  15 
word 12 : monkey  15 
word 13 : carrot  15 
word 14 : penguin 15 
word 15 : bottle  15
```

how to implement this case guide me thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to use a [*MultiMap*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)

Comment: I wrote my code using hashmap and now should I proceed with a multimap ???

Comment: Replace the HashMap with a MultiMap and most of your code should remain unchanged. When you read the elements at the end - you should order the keySet() and iterate it in-order fetching multiple values for each key. Nice & easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `newList` is sorted by `getCount` then the simpliest way to print words with same `count` as last printed word is:

```
    int k; // init k before the cycle
    for (k = 0; k < listSize; k++) {

        Words w = newList.get(k);

        System.out.println("Word : " + ++j + " " + w.getWord() + " "
                + w.getCount());

        // System.out.println(w.getWord());

    }

    if (k > 0) {
        int lastCount = newList.get(k - 1).getCount(); // last printed count
        // print words from the k-th
        while (k < newList.size()
               && newList.get(k).getCount() == lastCount) {
            Words w = newList.get(k);

            System.out.println("Word : " + ++j + " " + w.getWord() + " "
                    + w.getCount());

            ++k;
        }
    }
```